# Is $F\subset F(a,b)$ a Galois extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I know that $F\subset F(a)$ and $F\subset F(b)$ are the Galois extensions of degree $n$ and $m$ respectively, $(n,m)=1$.

1) How can I show that $F\subset F(a,b)$ is the Galois extension either?

2) How can I prove that $G(F(a,b)/F)\cong G(F(a)/F) \times G(F(b)/F)$?

So far:

1) I tried to check if $F\subset F(a,b)$ is algebraic, normal and separable.

It's algebraic since finite. It's normal iff it's a splitting field for some polynomial, so I take the polynomial $fg$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial for $a$ and $g$ is the minimal polynomial for $b$. But why is it separable?

I am not sure if it's useful, but I've proved moreover that $F(a)\cap F(b)=F$ so $a\notin F(b)$ and $b\notin F(a)$.

2) I have no idea how to do this part.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You have got your inclusion signs wrong, you should write $F(a) \supset F$. etc.

Comment: Oh, of course. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f, g$ be the minimal polynomials of $a, b$ over $F$.

Since $F(a)/F$ is Galois, the roots of $f$ are distinct, and similarly those of $g$. You have already noted that $f$ and $g$ have no roots in common. Therefore $F(a, b)$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $fg$, which has distinct roots, and thus $F(a,b)/F$ is a Galois extension, with $\lvert F(a, b) : G \rvert = mn$.

Let

- $G$ be the Galois group of $F(a,b)/F$,
- $H$ the Galois group of $F(a)/F$,
- $K$ the Galois group of $F(b)/F$.

Restrictions give us a group homomorphism
$$
\phi : G \to H \times K.
$$
Now note that $\lvert G \rvert = m n = \lvert H \rvert \cdot \lvert K \rvert$. And $\phi$ is injective, as if $g \in G$ acts trivially on both $F(a)$ and $F(b)$, it has to be trivial.

Hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism.